# Objective C - How to search in static cells

Tags: objective-c, search, static, cells

I am making an application in XCode and I need help implementing the search bar so it can search in the `TableView`. But the `TableView` has not Prototype cells but static cells and I can only find tutorials for prototype cells.

I don't even know if it's possible to search in static cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter prototype or static, you need to use Custom Cell.  Subclass UITableViewCell to create your Search Field, etc . For Static Cell, you do not need to implement cellForRowAtIndexPath:, it will load up automatically.